# htaccess to redirect main domain

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, web, dns

I have a htaccess that redirects my main domain "www.main.com" to "www.main.com/DBS2010".
The htaccess works but my url changes to "www.main.com/DBS2010" can I make the url stay as "www.main.com"?

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?main.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ DBS2010 [L]
```

Comment: This should be on serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code for that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?main\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ DBS2010 [L]
```

This will not change URL in browser to `/DBS2010'.